# Prevent fork bomb when using interactive commands (like script) in .bashrc

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal, shell

I've often wanted to log the output of Terminal. So I tried to set `script` to run at startup; in my .bashrc file I put:

```
script ~/Logs/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S")
```

Because the commands in my .bashrc file are run whenever I open an interactive terminal, I thought this would do what I wanted.

However, because `script` itself opens a new terminal during the course of its execution, I instead ended up with a fork bomb:

```
Last login: Sat May  9 12:02:43 on ttys001
Script started, output file is /Users/mchenja/Logs/2015-05-09.12-14-37
Script started, output file is /Users/mchenja/Logs/2015-05-09.12-14-37
Script started, output file is /Users/mchenja/Logs/2015-05-09.12-14-37
Script started, output file is /Users/mchenja/Logs/2015-05-09.12-14-37
Script started, output file is /Users/mchenja/Logs/2015-05-09.12-14-37
Script started, output file is /Users/mchenja/Logs/2015-05-09.12-14-37
[mchenja@mycomp ~]$
```

Any tips on how to ensure that `script` is run exactly once when I open a new interactive terminal?

If it matters, this is on OS X, although I believe the same thing would happen in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reflected on @Thomas Dickey's answer via the "guard variable" and your situation. There are some tricky things going on here and it depends on your environment.

If you're logged into a workstation running X windows, when you log in, the `.bash_profile` file is read (typically, though I Cannot say for sure about all editions of Linux; it also depends on your login shell). That would start your `script` session, so that's a bad thing. Further, when you log into a terminal from within X, it *will not* read `.bash_profile`, but only `.bashrc`, *unless* you tell the terminal software to tell bash that it is a login shell, in which case just the opposite happens.

So here are a few tips:

- Use $SHLVL to determine if you are at a "top level" invocation of bash, or possibly within an X login session, or possibly within a term/command-prompt within X (or maybe the console!). You can use the `tty` command to distinguish between console login and terminal login (`tty |grep -q ^/dev/tty && echo "is console"`)
- `.bash_profile` will only be read once per `login session` ... normally. You can also force its reading by invoking bash with `-l`.
- If it's a login shell, `.bashrc` *will not be* auotmatically read. You run it by sourcing it from within `.bash_profile`.
- I believe you want to make sure `script` is not re-entrant. That is, if you're in a shell with `script` running, and you create a sub-shell, you don't want `script` to run again.
- What happens if you run `screen` within `script`?
- `screen` has a logging feature which might be more suitable than script. Then you have other problems such as, what happens when you have multiple terminal windows open? Do they each have a separate screen session?

Comment: I'm an idiot... as you suggested, putting it in .bash_profile instead of .bashrc did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You would have to set your own special variable to be tested in `.bash_profile`, e.g.,

```
if [ -z "$IN_MY_SCRIPT" ]
then
    export IN_MY_SCRIPT=$(date)
    script ~/Logs/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S")
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering the "prevent fork bomb" question in the title, not the one you actually asked. ;)

Put Hard `nproc` limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf` as enforced by PAM.

Just a suggestion:

```
 *        soft   nproc   500
 %users   soft   nofile  256
```

But this might just screw with something like Apache or MySQL.